# Open, save and close any file

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a simple macro which will open, save and close an Excel file say myworkbook.xlsx but I am unable to do this. My file myworkbook.xlsx is at location:

`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Temp\myworkbook.xlsx`

I have written code as

```
Sub openSaveClose()
  Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Temp\files\myworkbook.xlsx" // This is working fine
  Workbooks("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Temp\myworkbook.xlsx").Save 
End sub
```

The error is:

> Run time error 9. Subscript out of range

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you would like to do. It looks like you would like to copy the file as is in another location. Right?

Comment: @Michele Thank you for your response.. 

No. I am not copying it to another location.

I just want to open,save and close a any simple excel file using macro.

If you have any code for this then kindly share :)

Answer (score 7):

You only need to specify the path when opening the file:

```
Sub openSaveClose()
  Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Temp\files\myworkbook.xlsx"
  Workbooks("myworkbook.xlsx").Save
  Workbooks("myworkbook.xlsx").Close
End sub
```

Using an object variable, you can do the following (then no need to use the workbook's *name* in the Save/Close statements):

```
Sub openSaveClose()
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Temp\files\myworkbook.xlsx")
  wb.Save
  wb.Close
End sub
```

Comment: ++ nice :) BTW you can write `wb.Save` and `wb.Close` together as `wb.Close (True)`

Comment: Very nice, thanks for extra efficiencies, David and Siddharth.